# Relation of top and bottom types given multiple universes

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

This is something that I haven't seen mentioned in any literature.
In a type theory (extensional, intuitionistic, Martin Lof variant), given two ordered Tarski Universes such that $U_i < U_{i+1}$, each extended with $\top$ and $\bot$, what is the relation between $\top$, $\bot$ and the two Universes (if there is any)?

Based on my personal understanding of type theory,
$$\frac{U_i\vdash U_i(\top)}{U_i(\top)\vdash U_{i+1}\ \land\ U_i(\top) \equiv U_{i+1}(\bot)}$$
but I'm not sure.

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but what are the meaning of universes extending $\top$ and $\bot$?